# Regex Postgres More than one dot

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I need to return the fields that have more than one `.` in a specific column.

Now I have this query:

```
select * 
from table 
where column ~ '\.{2,}?';
```

But for some reason it returns nothing. If I use something like  `'A{2,}?'` it works. Apparently the problem is the dot.

Comment: Why the question mark in your regex? Also, maybe you can provide examples of what you want (and don't want) to match with your query.

Comment: I need to find strings with more than one dot. Example:
I need to match "200.000.00" or "200.000.000.00" or " 200.000.000.000.00" etc.
I don't need to match " 200.00"

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you really matching strings with more than one dot? Or are you matching numbers greater than a certain amount? If it's the second, Postgres type casting might be faster and more accurate than a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns null since the dots are not next two each other. You have to consider the occurrences of the characters in the order of your regex meta characters. You could try this instead:

```
select * 
from table 
where column ~ '\.\d{3}\.';
```

Or instead of just focusing on the dot characters start parsing the string as a whole and consider the numbers as well:

```
where column ~ '^\d{3}\.\d{3}\.';
```

Comment: Thanks. I just changed it to find N caracters. It ended like this: '\.\d{2,}\.'

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `like`?

```
where column like '%.%.%'
```